# Set a "persistent" variable among shell script executions in crontab

Tags: bash, shell, variables, cron

I have a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ x -eq 1 ] && [ /someothercondition ]; then
  IS_CONNECTED=0
else
  IS_CONNECTED=1
fi
```

I would like to keep the "IS_CONNECTED" variable throughout all executions of crontab. So for example if I have a job scheduled every minute:

```
* * * * * bash /home/some/path/to/file.sh
```

I'd like to "keep" the value of the variable among the script executions. For example, if the first run sets IS_CONNECTED to 1, in the second run IS_CONNECTED will already be 1 at the beginning.

Unfortunately, environment variables are not easily set on crontab. Are there other ways?

Comment: You pretty much have to store that in a file or something similar -- variables are local to each process. (Note subprocesses inherit a copy of environment variables, but it's a *copy* so changes to one copy don't affect the other).

Comment: Btw.: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: @Cyrus the script is just an example, it's not my real script. It's just to explain the basic idea, it doesn't need syntactic help.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you, that explains a lot. Could you be more specific though? Do you mean a file to read and write everytime?

Comment: If you want to retain values between subsequent calls, why not just have a single process that stays running (and retaining values) and just sleeps till the next minute instead of starting afresh?

Comment: @John Something like that, though it'll depend a bit on how you want to use it. For instance, if you're going to have multiple scripts running at once and they need to update each other "live", things could get very complex. Actually, even if two scripts that use it *could* run at the same time, you have to be careful of [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#In_software) (where if things happen in the wrong order, you get wanted results).

Comment: That's not a bad idea, actually. I didn't think of that. Thank you for your help.